# asio: awaitable operator|| don't return when timer expires

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

The attached code, extracted from a larger codebase, has behavior that I cannot
explain.

The problem is in the `run` function where I would like to wait up to a maximum
time that the awaitable returned by async_initiate completes.

The async operation initiated by `async_initiate` never completes (in this
example because I never call the handler, in the real program because it is
waiting for a network packet), but the coroutine is stuck on the co_await even
if the timer expires.

The asio version is the one shipped with boost 1.81.0

```cpp
#include <boost/asio/any_completion_handler.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/any_io_executor.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/async_result.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/co_spawn.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/detached.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_context.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/use_awaitable.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;

// this function exists only to keep the io_context busy
asio::awaitable<void> busy() {
    auto exec = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;

    using asio::ip::udp;
    auto socket = udp::socket(exec, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 40000));

    uint8_t msg[1024];
    std::cout << "reading from socket...\n";
    co_await socket.async_receive(asio::buffer(msg), asio::use_awaitable);
}

std::optional<asio::any_completion_handler<void(int)>> stored;

asio::awaitable<void> run() {
    std::cout << "run() called\n";

    auto exec = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    asio::steady_timer timer{exec, std::chrono::seconds(2)};

    auto initiate = [&]([[maybe_unused]] asio::any_completion_handler<void(int)> handler) {
        // don't call the handler on purpose
        //
        // move it on `stored` only for the sake of this example, to rule out
        // any side-effect of the handler destructor
        stored = std::move(handler);
    };

    co_await (asio::async_initiate<const asio::use_awaitable_t<>, void(int)>(initiate, asio::use_awaitable)
              || timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable));
    std::cout << "done\n";
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context io;

    asio::co_spawn(io, busy, asio::detached);
    asio::co_spawn(io, run, asio::detached);
    io.run();
}
```

I know that operator|| is waiting for "a success" but this should not be the cause of the problem because the time completes (or should complete) without an error

Comment: I am not completely sure, but I suspect that you need to implement cancellation for the async operation started by the call to `async_initiate`. Otherwise, how could the || operator cancel the first operation if the second succeeds.

Comment: @JakobStark this makes a lot of sense :) I'm going to study the topic on the asio website, do you have some reference to share?

Comment: Unfortunately the cancellation mechanism is not (yet) doumented very well. There is a very good (imho) talk on youtube about it though: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hHk5OXlKVFg

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The async operation initiated by async_initiate never completes (in this example because I never call the handler,

If you don't complete, you can't witness that it completes with `operation_aborted` either.

> in the real program because it is waiting for a network packet), but the coroutine is stuck on the co_await even if the timer expires.

Let's put that to the test:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d9aa0314f64ed86)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

asio::awaitable<void> busy() {
    auto exec = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;

    using asio::ip::udp;

    try {
        while (true) {
            auto socket = udp::socket(exec, udp::endpoint(udp::v4(), 40000));

            uint8_t msg[1024];
            std::cout << "reading from socket..." << std::endl;
            auto n = co_await socket.async_receive(asio::buffer(msg), asio::use_awaitable);

            std::cout << "received " << n << " bytes" << std::endl;
        }
    } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
        auto const& ec = se.code();
        std::cout << "receive failed: " << ec.message() << " at " << ec.location() << std::endl;
    }
}

asio::awaitable<void> run() {
    std::cout << "run() called\n";

    auto exec = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    asio::steady_timer timer{exec, 2s};

    co_await (busy() || timer.async_wait(asio::use_awaitable));
    std::cout << "done\n";
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context io;

    asio::co_spawn(io, run, asio::detached);
    io.run();
}
```

[image]

Works as advertised. If you prefer to avoid exception handling, you can use `as_tuple` or `redirect_error`:

```
asio::awaitable<void> busy() {
    auto exec = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;

    for (error_code ec; !ec.failed();) {
        auto socket = asio::ip::udp::socket{exec, {{}, 40'000}};

        uint8_t msg[1024];
        std::cout << "reading from socket..." << std::endl;
        auto n = co_await socket.async_receive(asio::buffer(msg), redirect_error(asio::use_awaitable, ec));

        std::cout << "received " << n << " bytes (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

### Your Own Async Initiatiation?

Your own IO objects/operations may not support cancellation. If you want, implement is on `cancellation_slot`. Let's also show how to use a work guard to keep the execution context alive:

```
template <typename Token>
auto async_stuff(Token token) {
    auto initiate = [](auto handler) {
        auto cs   = asio::get_associated_cancellation_slot(handler);
        auto work = make_work_guard(asio::get_associated_executor(handler));

        cs.assign([work, h = std::move(handler)](asio::cancellation_type type) mutable {
            using ct = asio::cancellation_type;
            if (ct::none != (type & ct::terminal))
                std::cout << "cancellation_type terminal" << std::endl;
            if (ct::none != (type & ct::partial))
                std::cout << "cancellation_type partial" << std::endl;
            if (ct::none != (type & ct::total))
                std::cout << "cancellation_type total" << std::endl;

            work.reset();
            std::move(h)(asio::error::operation_aborted, -1);
        });
    };

    return asio::async_initiate<Token, void(error_code, int)>(initiate, token);
}
```

You can bind your cancellation slot like this:

**[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/72cf6fc400aff036)**

```
int main() {
    asio::thread_pool io(1);

    asio::cancellation_signal cancel;
    auto token = asio::bind_cancellation_slot(cancel.slot(), asio::use_awaitable);
    asio::co_spawn(io, async_stuff(token), asio::detached);

    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    cancel.emit(asio::cancellation_type::terminal);

    io.join();
}
```

The experimental operators use `parallel_group` which use cancellation slots under the hood.

Comment: Thank you! for the super-helpful response; supporting cancellation is one of the trickiest parts of an asynchronous library/framework